@Timeout of microprofile-fault-tolerance- not working ! Timeout Exception not occouring
Hi everyone I am facing issue in implementing timeout from the below dependency for on of our services, what is happenig that i am not getting any timeout exception flow is running as usual even after applying annotation.
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.fault-tolerance</groupId>
<artifactId>microprofile-fault-tolerance-api</artifactId>
<version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>

I am using spring boot 2.7.18, jdk 1.8
        @GetMapping(value = "/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return hello2();
    }
    
    @Timeout(unit = ChronoUnit.MILLIS, value = 100)
    public String hello2() {
         waitingMethod();
         return "no_timeout";
    }

    public void waitingMethod() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }


Please help!
The above code is replication of acutal scenerio, this is failing too?
I have tried multiple versions of this library but nothing works, using it with sigleton beans, objects but not working.

Sprng AOP works using proxies, which only works for external method calls not internal methods calls. Hence your @Timeout here is pretty much useless with an internal method call.

@M.Deinum this just example code, in the acutal scenerio these methods are in different services i.e contoller, and service,.

Then please provide actual code instead of psuedo dumbed down code.
